# how can I get more users to view/answer my questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, unanswered-questions, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I sometimes find myself asking a question and it is only answered once... maybe twice... and I'm looking for a variety of answers.

For example, I asked [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214877/online-chat-how-do-i-implement-comet-programming-with-ajax-long-polling) and I was hoping a lot of people would share their thoughts an opinions, but only 1 user replied, and it wasn't very helpful.

How can I attract more users to answer my question, besides starting a bounty? I don't want to delete the question and re-post it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really recommend against "deleting and reposting". Really, a better option would be bumping it via edit, [as detailed in this similarly titled question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions "Which ridiculously is not on the Related list").

Comment: That is what I have been doing so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed: [in the post you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214877/online-chat-how-do-i-implement-comet-programming-with-ajax-long-polling) (in the part *Actual Question*) your question is quite broad (also note the **4** question marks in that paragraph).

Questions which are **broad in nature** or questions divided into **multiple sub-questions** tend to get fewer answers because not as many people feel qualified to give an in-depth answer for every single aspect of the problem.

Another aspect may be **sheer luck** (asking the question at the right time - that is, when someone capable and interested in answering it is). And be aware that some of the harder / more niche Q&A still get low views.

*Don't read this as personal criticism (it looks like you took some time to write the question).*

Comment: No not at all... I appreciate your honesty and thanks for your response. It makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Post a link on Twitter, your Facebook page, your blog or any other site where you might reach someone who'll know the answer.